# Kubernetes cluster on AWS,The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused

Tags: kubernetes

On my vagrant VM,I created kops cluster

```
 kops create cluster \
       --state "s3://kops-state-1000" \
       --zones "eu-central-1a","eu-central-1b" \
       --master-count 3 \
       --master-size=t2.micro \
       --node-count 2 \
       --node-size=t2.micro \
       --ssh-public-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub\
       --name jh.mydomain.com \
       --yes
```

I can list cluster with kops get cluster

```
jh.mydomain.com aws eu-central-1a,eu-central-1b
```

The problem is that I can not find .kube repository. When I go for

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:11:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Is this somehow related to my virtual box deployment or not? I am aware that  the command *kubectl* works on the master node because that's where *kube-apiserver* runs. Does this mean that my deployment is workers node?

I tried what Vasily suggested

```
kops export kubecfg $CLUSTER_NAME
W0513 15:44:17.286965    3279 root.go:248] no context set in kubecfg

--name is required
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to obtain kubeconfig from your cluster and save it as ${HOME}/.kube/config:

```
kops export kubecfg $CLUSTER_NAME
```

After that you may start using kubectl.

Comment: please replace $CLUSTER_NAME with your cluster name, e.g. jh.mydomain.com

Answer (score 1):

It seems that kops didn't configure the context of the cluster in your machine
You can try the following command:

```
kops export kubecfg jh.mydomain.com
```

You can also find the *config* file at S3->kops-state-1000->jh.mydomain.com->config
After downloading the config file you can try:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig={config you downloaded} version
```

Also, it's kinda unrelated to your question, but it may be not a bad idea to have a look at [gossip-based kubernetes cluster](http://blog.arungupta.me/gossip-kubernetes-aws-kops/). To try that feature, you just need to create a cluster with kobs using `--name=something.k8s.local`